# How to use microformats

Tags: microdata, microformats, rich-snippets

I'm trying to add some microformats to my site and testing with google Structured Data Testing Tool is giving me a

> *Warning: Itemtype not recognized.*

What would be the right syntax to get it through?

```
<div class="vote-message" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Rating">
  <span itemprop="value">
    <span itemprop="bestRating">
      5.0/<strong>5</strong>
    </span>
    Bewertung (<span itemprop="ratingValue">3</span> Stimmen)
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using **microdata**, not **microformats**. I edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because http://data-vocabulary.org has been shuttered and replaced with http://schema.org/; if you replace your itemtype attribute's value to `itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating"`, the warning goes away, and you can see the extracted structured data in the structured data tool.